# Access Database turn on aggregate type through VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can anyone review my code here and see where I did wrong. My objective is to turn on the Aggregate Type in the Datasheetview after creating the query. So far

```
    Function LoopQuery(ByVal tempProj As Double)
Dim strSQL As String 
Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef 
Dim ProjNumb As Double 
ProjNumb = tempProj
strSQL = "sql code...."
With CurrentDb
Set qdfTemp = .CreateQueryDef(ProjNumb, strSQL)    
   qdfTemp.Fields(21).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0 'add the Aggregate Total on Total Hours
   qdfTemp.Fields(23).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0   'add the Aggregate Total on Total Costs
   qdfTemp.Fields(24).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0   'add the Aggregate Total on Total Discounted 
End With
```

I know I am close, my problem is that

```
qdfTemp.Fields(21).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0 'add the Aggregate Total on  Hours 
qdfTemp.Fields(23).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0 'add the Aggregate Total on Total Costs 
qdfTemp.Fields(24).Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0 'add the Aggregate Total on Total Discounted
```

does not create the Sum Total row that I need.

I used this [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21547b64-8317-4759-a50b-e339427102f2/access-2007-aggregatetype-field-property) on the msdn forum for the property reference, but it doesnt' seem to work on my query. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

upon playing around, i realize the AggregateType.value = 0 did pass through, but the "Totals Row" wasnt visible. Once i clicked on the Totals Records under the Home ribbon, I was able to see that it did get summed for me. So now my question is.

How do I set visible the Totals row on the bottom of the datasheet view?  I tried

```
 currentdb.qdfTemp.Properties("TotalsRow") = True
```

but its returning an error

Comment: @HansUp hi, thanks for answering, the QueryDef did get saved, there are no error message thrown which is why i m confused. The .createquerydef part works , the DB is in ACCDB format

Comment: @HansUp I am using access 2007 , and the file is ACCDB , regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, you must set the query's *TotalsRow* property to True before your field's totals can be displayed.

However the *TotalsRow* property does not exist when you first create the `QueryDef`.  So you must create the property ...

```vb
Set qdfTemp = .CreateQueryDef(ProjNumb, strSQL)
qdfTemp.Properties.Append _
    qdfTemp.CreateProperty("TotalsRow", dbBoolean, True)
```