# How can I use VBA to add a totals row at the end of new table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have this VBA code to create a new table:

```vb
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "SELECT FGE50IPE_GESUPE.DATPRP, " _
       & "Count(FGE50IPE_GESUPE.NUMSUP) AS NoSupp INTO table1 " _
       & "FROM FGE50IPE_GESUPE " _
       & "GROUP BY FGE50IPE_GESUPE.DATPRP;"
docmd.runsql strsql
```

I know that in MS-Access you can create totals via:
Navigation pane > Datasheet View > "Home" tab > click Totals...
as per this [MS Tip](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Sum-or-count-values-on-a-datasheet-with-a-Total-row-d8393172-4ff4-4e54-8994-f6a0417b80d3?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA).

Is it possible to do this via VBA?

I want to prepare the final view of my table with total, average, ... 
and because my program using custom ribbons and the std tab isn't visible, the total row can't be added from final user.

Comment: Please do not yell at us IN AN ALL CAPS TITLE.

Comment: sorry, I was filling out another form in CAPS TITLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missing to read  the TableDef, solution: `db.TableDefs("table1").Properties("TotalsRow") = True`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the accepted answer, I got an error that the property didn't exist. So I did this instead:

```
CurrentDb().TableDefs("TableName").Properties.Append CurrentDb().CreateProperty("TotalsRow", dbBoolean, True)
```

This added the totals row, but with only the word "Totals", and no numbers. The get the totals to appear, I had to set the `AggregateType` property for each field. Thus the code that finally works is:

```
dim oDB as Database
Set oDb = CurrentDb()
With oDb.TableDefs("TableName")
    .Properties.Append oDb.CreateProperty("TotalsRow", dbBoolean, True)
    .Fields("Field 1").Properties.Append oDb.CreateProperty("AggregateType", dbLong, 0)
    .Fields("Field 2").Properties.Append oDb.CreateProperty("AggregateType", dbLong, 0)
    etc.
  End With
```

The same code works for queries by changing `TableDefs` to `QueryDefs`.

Where I found this information: [*Access World*](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/using-totals-row-in-a-table-via-vba.304741/), [*StackOverflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272833/access-database-turn-on-aggregate-type-through-vba), and [*UtterAccess*](https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/1940218). The third source is where I found out that `AggregateType` has to be set as `dbLong`. I first tried `dbInteger`, which makes more sense for small numbers (or even `dbByte`), but the numbers did not show up until I used `dbLong`.